# How to force always solid line plot in Octave

Tags: octave, x11

The following script should generate a 440Hz sine wave, display the first part of it as a solid line x-t-plot and play the whole wave on the audio output device:

```
% Octave script to demonstrate

% frequency
f = 440;    % Hz

% duration
duration = 3;   % s

% sampling rate
fs = 44100; % Hz

% one second duration of time points to be sampled
t = ( 0:duration*fs-1 ) / fs;

% compose the wave
wave = 0.2 * sin( 2*pi * f * t );

% duration to display
td = 0.02;  # s

% display x-t-diagram
fig = plot( t(t<td), wave(t<td), '-' );

% play sound
sound( wave, fs );
```

On one computer it does exactly this. However, on another with the same Linux OS, the line always appears as dashed and is hardly visible:

[image: plot window displaying the line as dashed]

How can I tell the `plot` command to use a solid line on both computers on the X terminal?

I do not use any `.octaverc` and the system-wide `octaverc` below `/usr/share/octave` is unmodified on both computers.

When I plot to a file using `saveas`, the plot is saved with solid lines even if it appears with dashes on the terminal.

Adding the line

```
graphics_toolkit( 'gnuplot' );
```

before the plot command will indeed produce a solid line, however this will show up only after the sound has finished, which is not what I want.

Comment: Is the sound part important to show the problem with the plot? If you just run `plot(sin(0:0.1:10))` on both system, is one still dashed?

Comment: @Andy: The plot is still dashed if I comment out that line. The line was only included to show what I want to do.

Comment: Looks like aliasing? Can you please increase the linewidth to 2 or 3 and see if it is still dashed?

Comment: @Andy: Thanks, yes, that solves the issue! Please add this as an answer, so I can accept it. `plot( t(t<td), wave(t<td), '-', 'LineWidth', 3 );`

Comment: So you should check your antialisaing settings. I remember that I once had the same problem with a Intel? OpenGL driver

Comment: @Andy: Thanks, where do I find Octave's antialiasing settings?

Comment: Adding after (nor before) the `plot` the command `set( gcf, 'graphicssmoothing', 'on' );` does not change the look of the graph.

Comment: No, I think there is a problem with your X settings or your GPU driver. Nothing which can changed inside GNU Octave. I have one Thinkpad where I just set the default linewitdh to 2 in .octaverc but this is only a workaround

Comment: @Andy: Thanks, I'll go with your workaround, too.